# Magento 2 - Add admin user to order

Tags: magento2, sales-order, custom-attributes, extension-attributes

I created an external WebApp that communicates via REST API to my Magento instance (Magento version installed is 2.1.13).
This WebApp will be used by shop's operators to sell the same shop products to physical customers at certain events.
These operators will create a quote (cart) with customer items and they then will register the customer to Magento (if he/she is not registered yet) and place the order for them.
Now my doubt comes in: is there a way to associate the shop operator with the order? 
The operator will be an admin user with limited permission (customer and order management), and ideally, I would be able to filter the order by shop operator.
Is this possible?

Comment: By default no. You need to customization for this.

Comment: I thought so. Do you know a way that I could try to accomplish what I asked?